# Ошибка при парсинге в R

Tags: json, парсер, r

При запуске скрипта, который тянет вакансии с HH столкнулся с ошибкой:

Error in open.connection(con, "rb") :    Timeout was reached: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Ошибка выскакивает в рандомное время, то на 10 странице парсинга, то на 100.
Вот скрипт:

```
# Scrap vacancies
{site <- "https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text="
Keyword <- "Менеджер+по+персоналу"
pagenumber <- "&vacancy_search_fields=name\"&page="
Keyword_UTF8 <- iconv(Keyword,"Windows-1251","UTF-8")
Keyword <- curlEscape(Keyword_UTF8)
url1 <- paste0(site,Keyword,pagenumber)
Url2 <-gsub("%2B","+",url1)}
# Создаю дата фрейм, он может быть любым
vacanciesdf <- data.frame(
  Name = character(),  # Название компании
  Name = character(), # Название вакансии
  Currency = character(), # Валюта
  From = character(), # Минимальная оплата
  Area = character(), # Город
  Requerement = character(), # Требуемые навыки
  responsibility = character(), 
  stringsAsFactors = T) 

# заполняею датафрейм данными со страниц ХХ
for (pageNum in 0:100) { # Всего страниц
  data <- fromJSON(paste0(Url2, pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, # 1 Город
    data$items$salary$currency, # 2 Валюта
    data$items$salary$from, # 3 Минимальная оплата
    data$items$salary$to, # 4 Максимальная оплата
    data$items$salary$gross, # 5 до налога?
    data$items$employer$name, # 6 Название компании
    data$items$snippet$requirement,# 7 Требуемые навыки
    data$items$snippet$responsibility, # 8 описание обязанностей
    data$items$name, # 9 название вакансии
    data$items$id)) # 10 id  вакансии
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

Comment: Может просто не хотят, чтоб их парсили?

Comment: Ну резюме они закрыли, там другая ошибка выскакивает. А вакансии вроде можно было) У меня этим скриптом до 2к вакансий вытягивалось, то есть явно где-то мой косяк(

Comment: Скорее всего это бан (возможно временный) из-за количества запросов с одного IP.